Azure Functions V4 (Typescript) Can't get Route parameters
I am currently migrating my Azure Functions from V3 to V4 in Typescript. Now I have the strange behaviour, that I can get the route parameters only when it is a string. If I pass a number as parameter, it won't be in the request.params object.
For Example:
http://localhost:7071/api/test/{parameter}
http://localhost:7071/api/test/test
results in { "parameter": "test"}
but if I call
http://localhost:7071/api/test/1
the request.params object is empty.
Anybody had a similar issue?
Attached is a sample Function code
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";

export async function RenderFiles(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
    context.log(request.params)
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: "Hello, World!"
    };
    
};

app.http('test', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: RenderFiles,
    route: 'test/{parameter}'
});


and the package.json
{
  "name": "functionsv4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.x",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "main": "dist/src/{index.js,functions/*.js}"
}


You can pass the int parameters like http://localhost:7071/api/test/'10'.

When we pass String parameter values in URLs, we can specify it directly without any quotes (test), but for int parameter values we need to pass the int values inside the quotes('10').
Code :
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";

export async function RenderFiles(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
    context.log(request.params)
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: "Hello, World!"
    };    
};

app.http('test', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: RenderFiles,
    route: 'test/{parameter}'
});

Browser Output :
I passed the int parameter value in the browser  as shown below,
http://localhost:7071/api/test/'10'


Terminal Output :
I was able to see the parameter as int in the below output.


yeah, totally get that, but all it does is, that you are converting it to a string, where you need to get rid of the ' afterwards to get back your initial value.

Using quotes around numbers in URLs converts them to strings. To retain numerical values, pass them without quotes and handle the conversion back to integers in your code if necessary.
